# Can't find entry point (_ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv) in DLL (filepath)

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64, msys2

## The error

The exact error is the title of the question.
[image: A picture of the error.]

It happens when I use `vectorName.push_back()` function.
I recreated it with just this simple code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> vec = {};
    vec.push_back(2);
    return 0;
}
```

## Compiler and setup information

I'm using [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/), and
I set it up using [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

I have no idea if this is relevant or not, but I used tdm-gcc before this.

## Research

A fix is almost nowhere to be found, or I just didn't look hard enough. I have found some posts about the `_ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv`, but not with entry point. And because I didn't find anything about this exact issue, I didn't try anything.

Comment: Do you get this error when you *build* your program, or when you *run* your program?

Comment: After a quick search it seems to be because a possible mismatch between the GCC compiler version installed, and the GCC standard C++ installation. What version of GCC do you have installed? Have you tried to install different versions of GCC?

Comment: Move `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the top of the PATH. If this doesn't help, build with `-static` or copy the DLLs your program uses next to the .exe (`ntldd -R 123.exe` to get the list of dlls, ignore those not present in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`).

Comment: It happened when I ran the program that was compiled. The version is 12.2.0. The build doesn't give out any errors. I went back to tdm-gcc because that still works.

Comment: Since I can't reproduce this in the MSYS2 shell, I would guess this is an issue with your VSCode environment.  What happens if you run `g++ -Wall test.cpp && ./a.exe` to compile and run your code in MSYS2's MinGW 64-bit shell?  What is the output of `which g++`?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I'd guess it runs without an error in the msys2 shell, but not when double-clicked it in Windows explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem:
"the procedure entry point _zst28__throw_bad could not be located in the dynamic link library"

(with msys2 mingw64)

Solution:
Modify the system environment variables (requires admin rights)

Start the windows commandline (cmd.exe) as admin (right-click run as administrator).
Then enter this command:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Then edit the PATH at the bottom (under Systemvariables), and make sure that C:\msys64\mingw64\bin is **right at the top position**.

**Done.**

Check as follows in cmd:

```
echo %PATH%
```

You can also non-persistenly edit the PATH from a cmd as follows (also does not require admin rights):

```
set PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
```

Comment: In most cases, you [expand PATH instead of replacing](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html) it completely.

Answer (score 1):

i also found problem like this, on windows 10 use msys2.
when i try to build minimal.cpp example with cmake, build process is work and complete without error:

[image]

But when i try to run program the error say "**entry point not found**",
after searching what really wrong for several day, i found copying **libstdc++-6.dll** on same folder with program, make program working as expected.

[error window screenshot (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwfxP.png)

[image]

(Hopefully its help somebody in future)

Comment: Exactly this helped fix the error when I run my (“statically”) linked [minimal wxWidgets app](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/minimal/minimal.cpp). The file `libstdc++-6.dll` can be found in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\`.